# How to create center cropped thumbnail images from image url in android

Tags: android

I am using glide library for loading my images , i am showing entire images , i want to show thumbnail image. How to do it?

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(resized)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_review)
            .crossFade().fitCenter()
            .into(triviaImage);
```

I have tried scaleType:fitXY and scaleType:centerCrop nothing worked.

```
please see image
```

[image]

Comment: An official solution [click on it](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-thumbnails)

Comment: please show your xml file ,.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use `override(width, height)` as shown here:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(resized)
    .asBitmap()
    .override(400, 400) // smaller the size, lower the quality of Image
    .centerCrop()
    .error(R.drawable.image_error_placeholder)
    .into(triviaImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Glide  
    .with( context )
    .load( resized )
    .thumbnail( 0.1f )
    .into( triviaImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem by this -

```
 Glide.with(context)
                  .load(myImageUrl)
                  /*Here "myImageUrl" is the original image url*/
                  .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(myThumbImageUrl).centerCrop())
                  /*Here "myThumbImageUrl" is the thumb image url*/
                  .into(view);
```